# How can I repair slices in fibercement siding?

Tags: siding

In the process of removing caulk between butt joints, the contractor sliced down into the planks below the joint.  Now that the house has been repainted it's extremely obvious.  I'm not sure what my options are to minimize the look or having it repaired.

Comment: Why isn't this a contractual issue with the company who caused the damage? Your options are to skim with caulk and hope the surface damage doesn't dramatically shorten the finish lifespan, or to replace the siding.

Comment: Thanks isherwood...the contractor is coming over tomorrow. I have been trying to get a handle on what resolutions there might be so I can speak to the problem with him and know what options there are for repair.

Answer (score 2):

Everything i have read states it is best to replace a damaged plank but there are repair solutions.

Here are a couple of links to inform your discussion with your contractor.

[How to Repair Fiber Cement Siding - The Complete Guide](https://www.allurausa.com/blog/how-to-repair-fiber-cement-siding-the-complete-guide)

[Fiber Cement Siding Repair Advice & Specifications](https://inspectapedia.com/exterior/Siding_Fiber_Cement_Repair.php)

The second one is full of links to valuable info.